# PHP and XML: Dlvr.it does not work

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

My feeds are made with PHP and MYSQL into XML and then feedburner.

My problem is that dlvr.it cannot read new entries everytime I post.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<rss version="2.0">  
<channel>  
<title>MindWeather Thesis</title>  
<description>Latest News from my website</description>  
<link>http://www.mindweather.info</link>';  

$get_articles = "SELECT Fore_ID, Valid, Synopsis,
DATE_FORMAT(Issued,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as formatted_date   
FROM tblforecast ORDER BY Issued DESC LIMIT 15";  

$articles = mysql_query($get_articles) or die(mysql_error());  

while ($article = mysql_fetch_array($articles)){  

    echo '  
       <item>  
          <title>'.$article['Valid'].'-hour Forecast</title>  
          <description><![CDATA['.$article['Synopsis'].']]> </description>  
          <link>http://mindweather.info/fforecast.php?fore='.$article['Fore_ID'].'</link>    
          <pubDate>'.$article['formatted_date'].' GMT</pubDate>  
      </item>';  
} 
echo '</channel>
</rss>';
?>
```

The feedburner feed is located at: http://www.mindweather.info/feedz2.php

Your answers would be as of much help. Thanks!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem. What happened when you tried it? Did you get an error message? Did you get incorrect results?

Comment: It displays the results and no error message.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism to detect new entries in a feed is to identify them using their unique `<guid>`. Since your feed lacks that element, it's perfectly normal that this service cannot detect new entries.

It's as simple has addding something like : `<guid><?php echo $article['Fore_ID']; ?></guid>`, assuming of course that the `Fore_ID` is unique. Add them between the `<item>` and `</item>`

You should also make sure each `<link>` element is unique because this is another way feed readers try to detect new/unique entries when they fail to do so using that  `<guid>` element.

Comment: which part do i have to add the guid?

Comment: i made the links unique now but still it doesnt work. (updated code above)

Comment: Not sure what you did but there is still no <guid> element: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mindweather.info%2Ffeedz2.php